# calculation in function default argument

Tags: python, function, methods

I want to do a simple calc in the argument of a python function to make it default parameter like,

```
def simple_fun(df, cols = df.columns):
    print(cols)
```

I need `df.columns` as default argument (and not inside the function). Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do that *inside* the function; `df` is not defined (or at least, it's not the argument you will pass when `simple_fun` is called) when the default argument value is evaluated.

```
def simple_fun(df, cols=None):
    if cols is None:
        cols = df.columns
    print(cols)
```

The expression for a default argument value is evaluated when the function is *defined*, not when the function is called.

Comment: But if anyone is calling this function and he/she has dataframe with him/her then why can't he pass columns at that time ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi OP wanted to do the calculation based on the parameters *themselves*. Sure if somebody has a symbol `df` in the namespace which points to a dataframe can use if as the value of a default parameter but read chepner's answer once again.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I got the question of OP but not the logic behind this question. Why would I or you will do this ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi If someone passes the `cols` argument when calling the `simple_fun` function, the function uses it, otherwise it uses the `.columns` of the `df` which should have been provided as the first argument. But this happens when the function gets called.

Comment: I felt the usecase might be like this that df is generated  by other function call and OP is passing that other function_call directly to `simple_fun(other_func_that_is_generating_df(), cols=#Now there is no way to get dataframe)`

Comment: Basically, when you want the default argument value to be a *function* of another argument, rather than *independent* of the other arguments.

Comment: The proposed solution does not work.  Checking for `cols is None` does not distinguish the case that the value was not given at call-site, vs the value given explicitly as `None`.  It would be great if Python delayed evaluation of the argument value to call-time, and evaluated it in a scope where the variables to the right were already populated, and omitted computing the default if value given explicitly at call-site.
But alas, Python does not work this way.

Comment: The point is to use a value that would *not* be given explicitly. If `None` has no use other than to signal the lack of an explicit argument, what useful distinction do you draw between `simple_fun()` and `simple_fun(None)`? If `None` *does* have some other use, you pick a different sentinel. (Usually by creating a custom instance of `object` that has no other assigned use; see https://peps.python.org/pep-0661/ as well.)